# disable cmd output in lua

Tags: lua, cmd, output

I used following lua code to create some files and write some text append the the game.txt

```
function makeFiles()
os.execute( "mkdir season\\week1" )
newFile = io.open( "season\\week1\\game.txt", "a+" )
newFile:write('123')
newFile:close()
end

makeFiles()
```

The cmd told me something like: "season\week1" already exists (translated from German). I am searching for a way to disable the output from the CMD via lua. After running my script there shouldn't be a output in the CMD telling me messages, I need to run the code in a silent way, the user shouldn't see this. I ask because I need to deactivate outputs from cmd generally using lua.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a lua question. If you want to silence the output from shell commands you silence the shell command.

The simplest way to do that for *this specific* instance is to use (assuming your system has it) the `-p` argument to `mkdir` which silences the error on already existing directories.

You could also (if `-p` doesn't exist for example) simply test for the directory first `os.execute("test -d season\\week1 || mkdir season\\week1")`.

Finally, and more generally, if you don't want output from a command redirect the output to `/dev/null`: `os.execute("mkdir season\\week1 >/dev/null 2>&1")`.

The above assumes a linux-like environment. I don't know if cmd.exe has similar redirection capabilities though I imagine it does. (`>nul 2>nul` apparently according to YuHao's answer)

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can redirect standard output and standout error to `nul` like this:

```
os.execute( "mkdir season\\week1 >nul 2>nul")
```

On Unix, it's similar:

```
os.execute( "mkdir season/week1 &> /dev/null" )
```

Comment: Any idea how I can access 'nul' and get the output into my script?

Comment: Make a new question; hint: popen.

Comment: @user3714446 The other option is to use a log file to replace `nul`.

Answer (score 1):

I need to disable output to user, but I need to get the result from running a cmd command. I used this code now:

```
 f = assert (io.popen ('HELP'))
 --runs commands directly in cmd/terminal

 for line in f:lines() do
 --print(line)
end

f:close()
```